# How to create a two dimensional array of given size in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to create a square matrix of a given size. I know how to create a dynamic one-dimensional array of a given size. Doesn't the same work for two dimensinal arrays like the lines below?

```
cin>>size;
int* a[][]=new int[size][size]
```

Comment: Have a look at `std::vector`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> int* a[][]=new int[size][size]
> ```

No, this doesn't work.

```
main.cpp:4: error: only the first dimension of an allocated array may have dynamic size
    new int[size][size];
                  ^~~~
```

If the size of the rows were fixed then you could do:

```
// allocate an array with `size` rows and 10 columns
int (*array)[10] = new int[size][10];
```

In C++ you can't have raw arrays with two dimensions where both dimensions are dynamic. This is because raw array indexing works in terms of pointers; for example, in order to access the second row a pointer to the first needs to be incremented by the size of the row. But when the size of a row is dynamic the array doesn't know that size and so C++ doesn't know how to figure out how to do the pointer increment.

If you want an array with multiple dynamic dimensions, then you need to either structure the array allocations such that C++'s default array indexing logic can handle it (such as the top answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new) duplicate question), or you need to implement the logic for figuring out the appropriate pointer increments yourself.

For an array where each row has the same size I would recommend against using multiple allocations such as those answers suggest, or using a vector of vectors. Using a vector of vectors addresses the difficulty and dangerousness of doing the allocations by hand, but it still uses more memory than necessary and doesn't allow faster memory access patterns.

A different approach, flattening the multi-dimensional array, can make for code as easy to read and write as any other approach, doesn't use extra memory, and can perform much, much better.

A flattened array means you use just a single dimentional array that has the same number of elements as your desired 2D array, and you perform arithmetic for converting between the multi-dimensional indices and the corresponding single dimensional index. With `new` it looks like:

```
int *arr = new int[row_count * column_count];
```

Row `i`, column `j` in the 2d array corresponds to `arr[column_count*i + j]`. `arr[n]` corresponds to the element at row `n/column_count` and column `n% column_count`. For example, in an array with 10 columns, row 0 column 0 corresponds to `arr[0]`; row 0, column 1 correponds to `arr[1]`; row 1 column 0 correponds to `arr[10]`; row 1, column 1 corresponds to `arr[11]`.

---

You should avoid doing manual memory management using raw `new` and `delete`, such as in the case of `int *arr = new int[size];`. Instead resource management should be wrapped up inside a [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) class. One example of a RAII class for managing dynamically allocated memory is `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<int> arr(row_count * column_count);
arr[column_count*i + j]
```

You can further wrap the logic for computing indices up in another class:

```
#include <vector>

class Array2d {
  std::vector<int> arr;
  int columns;
public:
  Array2d(int rows, int columns)
  : arr(rows * columns)
  , columns(columns)
  {}

  struct Array2dindex { int row; int column; };

  int &operator[] (Array2dindex i) {
    return arr[columns*i.row + i.column];
  }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int size;
  std::cin >> size;

  Array2d arr(size, size);

  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
      arr[{i, j}] = 100;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
      std::cout << arr[{i, j}] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

---

Comment: I'm getting a compile error ` error: expected expression arr[{i, j}] = 100; 2darray.cpp:29:11: error: expected ']' 2darray.cpp:29:10: note: to match this '['                                                                                                    arr[{i, j}] = 100;

Answer (score -2):

If you're using C++11 you can also use std::array.

```
const int iRows = 3, iCols = 3; // number of rows and columns
std::array<std::array<int, iCols>, iRows> matrix;

// fill with 1,2,3  4,5,6  7,8,9
for(int i=0;i<iRows;++i)
    for(int j=0;j<iCols;++j)
        matrix[i][j] = i * iCols + j + 1;
```

This class also allows for bounds checking by using the function

```
std::array::at
```

which (just like operator[]) returns a const reference if the array-object is const-qualified or a reference if it is not. Please note that

```
std::array
```

is **not** a variable-sized array-type, like

```
std::vector
```

Comment: This one requires knowing the dimensions up front. It doesn't work if you don't know the dimensions until after user input. `cin >> size` in the example kills it.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int*>> a(size, std::vector<int*>(size));
```

This will create a dynamically allocated 2D array of `int*` with width and height equal to `size`.

Or the same with `new`:

```
int*** a = new int**[size];
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    a[i] = new int*[size];
...
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    delete a[i];
delete a;
```

Note that there's no `new[][]` operator in C++, you just have to call `new[]` twice.

However, if you want to do it with `new` and `delete` instead of `std::vector`, you should use smart pointers instead of raw pointers, for example:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int*>[]> a(new std::unique_ptr<int*>[size]);
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    a[i].reset(new int*[size]);
...
// No need to call `delete`, std::unique_ptr does it automatically.
```

Comment: while using the method with "new" I get an error "int** a shadows a parameter". Any idea why this occurs?

Comment: Maybe you have another variable called `a` somewhere?

Comment: yes, you are right, I already had declared a before. So, in this case, do I need to write a=new int*[size] or **a=new int*[size]?

Comment: I just get error in both cases, I don't know the reason

Comment: `**a` just derefences `a` twice, that's not what you want. If you want to do `a = new int*[size]` then `a` has to be declared as `int**`. Btw check my edit on the smart pointer solution.

Comment: Using a vector of vectors is not generally a good idea. If each row has its own independent size the such a structure is okay, but if every row has the same size then a vector of vectors will be slower and use more memory than a flattened 2d array.

Comment: Probably not in the specific case of this person asking the question, but it may be important to some people looking for 2d arrays in C++. Also there's little reason to do premature pesimization here even if performance isn't that important; faster code can be just as clean and readable.

Comment: True, but I'm pretty sure people serious about vector optimizations won't land on a -5 question about 2D array initialization syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately the top voted answers to the [question that does come up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new) on a search have IMO even worse answers.